# Gaussian processes regression in scikit learn without kernel gradient evaluation

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, gradient, gaussian

I am doing simple Gaussian regression using the module GaussianProcessesRegression in sklearn. However I am trying to implement my own kernel and not one provided by the module kernels.

I am having problems with the optimization of the hyperparameters (it might be that I have implemented the kernel gradient wrongly and I do not see the error). So my question is:

How can I run the method `fit' (where the optimization of the hyperparameters happens) of the GaussianProcessesRegression module without the evaluation of the kernel gradient during the optimization?

From the documentation it should be possible by setting the variable `eval_gradient=False' but in practice I cannot call any method with this variable.

This is an idea of the code I am using:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
import kernels as my_kernel

kernel1 = 1.0*my_kernel.RBF_D(length_scale=np.linspace(1,10,10), length_scale_bounds=(1e-3, 100.0))

gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel1, n_restarts_optimizer=10)
gp.fit(Xtrain,Ytrain)
hyperp = = gp.kernel_.get_params()
y_gp,y_train_std=gp.predict(Xtrain,return_std=True)
```

If I try to call

```
gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, n_restarts_optimizer=0,eval_gradient=False)
```

I have the error:

` Traceback (most recent call last):...

gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel1, n_restarts_optimizer=10,eval_gradient=False)
TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'eval_gradient' '

Similarly, if I try

`gp.fit(Xtrain, Ytrain, eval_gradient=False)`

` TypeError: fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'eval_gradient' '

Which was obvious that it was not working but I didn't have any other idea. Any hint on how to do this?

(The fact that I am using my own kernel is not relevant for this question)

Comment: Offer us a hint about what code you're currently running to attempt this.

Comment: I re-edited, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned "the documentation", http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessRegressor.html

It explains that GPR can call an optimizer you supply, which can specify `eval_gradient` when invoking the objective function.

Comment: Yes and I assumed that therefore there is a way to specify the same variable also to the default optimizer. But if it is possible I do not see how to do it.

Comment: The "unexpected keyword argument 'eval_gradient' " diagnostic is accurate, and matches the documentation. It looks like you want to write an `optimizer` callback and pass it to GPR.